# Retrieve data from client website on AWS via their API

Tags: php, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

Need to pull data from a https://api.domain.com address. I have a customerID and an api key.

I can use either asp or php.

I am very new to this and have no idea where to even start, tried to upload SDK to a apache website but nothing works so I am stuck, can anyone help me please?

After more reading the dashboard page I get from the url above  gets a JSON reply back from the AWS server, I cant find how to make that request from a php or what to do with the reply to show it as a table perhaps...

Comment: What have you done so far apart from uploading the SDK? That wont work just out of the box.. Do you even have an index.php and able to view that in a browser?

Comment: The AWS API is for interacting with AWS itself, not with web sites hosted by AWS.

Comment: I can add an index.php file to my website and it will show text. the http://api.awsdomain.com brings up an api dashboard which I can enter customer ID and get and I get results, just have no idea how I make a php page on my website to get at that data and display it

Comment: What did you try and it didn't work for you, like infrastructure setup, php issues, etc? Would you mind posting more specific issue?

Comment: I uploaded SDK to a folder on my website called aws, I navigated to aws-uploader.php but it comes up blank.

Comment: Which specific service you want to use?

Comment: Service? All I want to do is get data that is on a AWS system and present it on my website. I have been given a customer ID a Key and a url https://api.extensopro.com . If you go to url you see all I have.

Comment: If I grab the url the dashboard page produces I get a web page back with the information its pulled from the AWS server in comma delimited text, how do I make a pph page that will do that and allow me to display the data in a logical manner?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked for me.

Used an online program called Postman https://www.getpostman.com which creates a variety of API code with just a few clicks!